# Difficulties with Css Specificity

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to add a class specific to some divs, but It's not working.

The div itself:

```
<div class="form-control drop-down-select" >
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form-control.drop-down-select{
    max-width: 220px;
}
```

I do have some classes prior to the form-control, but isn't this speficiity high enough?

My console:
[image]

Comment: You need to use `.container-fluid .filters .filter-row .form-control.drop-down-select` (without the `[_ngcontent-...]` part generated by angular.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if the class selectors are on the same element or on descendants, it is always "specificity = total number of class selectors", so the other style wins. See e.g. this overview: https://specifishity.com/

You could add an ID selector to increase the specificity above the class selectors, or use `!important`, which is necessary quite often when trying to style third-party components.